# Vuejs-neo4j connector: Display all nodes from the query

Tags: vue.js, neo4j

I have successfully been able to connect and run queries to retrieve data from a neo4j db. The issue now is that I can only display one node from the result. How do I modify it to display all the nodes?

```
testQuery() {
  // Get a session from the driver
  const session = this.$neo4j.getSession();

  // Or you can just call this.$neo4j.run(cypher, params)
  session
    .run("MATCH (Ind:Country {name: 'India', result: 'Winners'})<-[: TOP_SCORER_OF]-(n) RETURN n.name  AS x")
    .then(res => {
      var x = res.records[0].get("x");
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
      console.log(x);

    })
    .then(() => {
      session.close();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it all in JavaScript via direct DOM manipulation then you'll need to loop through `records` and use something like [appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Alternatively, you can store `records` in your Vue app's data and then use the Vue [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) attribute inside of a tag such as `<li>`, `<div>`, etc